Documentation of $.taskName to access the current task in step functions
Does anyone know if there is any documentation for the $.taskName variable? I am trying to implement a Catch clause in my step function to catch exceptions for some tasks, and I would like to pass the task name into the error handler (which goes onto publish a CloudWatch metric about which task failed) I have in the Catch clause. I see some people use $.taskName, but I can't seem to find any official documentation about it. This question looks like asking about the same thing, but the accepted answer only says we can pass the execution arn from Context Object. The Context Object documentation doesn't mention anything about the taskName variable. Thanks!
